# Error when pushing to Heroku: Figaro::MissingKeys: Missing required configuration keys: ["config.secret_key"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables

I keep on getting this error when pushing to Heroku: `Figaro::MissingKeys: Missing required configuration keys: ["config.secret_key"]`.

I am using Figaro to manage my credentials and am not sure why the key is not getting picked up.

In figaro.rb:

```
Figaro.require_keys('config.secret_key')
```

In devise.rb:

```
config.secret_key = ENV['config.secret_key'] if Rails.env.production?
```

In application.yml:

```
config.secret_key: 'long string'
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem had to do with the name 'config.secret_key'. I guess that the period was throwing everything off. I changed it to 'devise_secret_key', and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong syntax in `application.yml`. It should be:

```
config.secret_key: 'long string'
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my original post, which I have since fixed. The line in my application.yml is actually `config.secret_key: 'long string'`. Not sure why it is not working.

Comment: Sometimes stopping and restarting spring helps